# Get index of value in hashset C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to retrieve index of value in `HashSet` ?

I have a hashset:

```
HashSet<int> allE = mesh.GetAllNGonEdges(nGonTV);
```

And I would like to retrieve index of value similar to arrays function:
`Array.IndexOf(...)`

Comment: `HashSet`'s idea is that items' order does not matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "index" is meaningless in a `HashSet` - it's not guaranteed to be the same as the insertion order, and it can change over time as you add and remove entries (in non-guaranteed ways, e.g. if you add a new entry it could end up in the middle, at the end, at the start; it could reorder everything else...) There's not even a guarantee that you'll see the same order if you iterate over the set multiple times *without* modifying it between times, although I'd *expect* that to be okay.

You can get the *current* index with something like:

```
var valueAndIndex = hashSet.Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index })
                           .ToList();
```

... but you need to be *very* aware that the index isn't inherent in the entry, and is basically unstable.